# Determining when $A(e_n) = \alpha_n\sum_{i=n}^{2n}e_i$ is a bounded linear function on $l^1(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Consider the space $S = l^1(\mathbb{N})$ over complex coefficients and define $A$ by $A(e_n) = \alpha_n\sum_{i=1}^{2n}e_n$ for the standard basis $\left(e_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $S$. I am trying to determine when $A$ is a bounded linear function, but currently I am stuck at showing that $A$'s codomain really is $l^1(\mathbb{N})$, which in turn seems to be equivalent for $A$ to be continuous. I mean the following: $u \equiv \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_ie_i, u_i\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |u_i| < \infty$. Now,

$$A\left(u\right) = A\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_ie_i\right)$$

and I would like to be able to conclude that

$$A\left(u\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty A(u_ie_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i\alpha_i\sum_{j=i}^{2i}e_i$$

But I don't really see an immediate way to conclude this. Being able to pull out the limit is equivalent to

$$||\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^NA(u_ie_i) - A(u)|| = \lim_{N\to\infty}||\sum_{i=1}^NA(u_ie_i) - A(u)|| = 0$$

but the problem is that we don't a priori know that $A(u)$ is, and hence concluding the convergence feels sketchy.

How should I proceed with this proof?

Comment: It matters what the $\alpha_n$ are. $A$ is certainly not bounded if the $\alpha_n$ are unbounded. Do we know any more about them?

Comment: $\|A(e_n)\|_1=2n|a_n|$. Thus, as long as $\sup_nna|a_n|<\infty$, $A$ would be bounded.

Comment: The operator $A:\ell^1\to \ell^1 $ is bounded iff $\sup_n\|Ae_n\|_1<\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{e}_k=\mathbb{1}_{k}$, that is, $\mathbf{e}_k(m)=1$ iff $m=k$.
Any $\mathbf{x}\in\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ can be written as
$$\mathbf{x}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbf{x}(n)\mathbf{e}_n$$

Notice that $\|A\mathbf{e}_n\|_1=2n|\alpha_n|$. Hence, if $C:=\sup_nn|\alpha_n|<\infty$ we have that
$$\|A\mathbf{x}\|_1\leq\lim_N\sum^N_{k=1}|\mathbf{x}(k)|\|A\mathbf{e}_k\|_1\leq C\lim_N\sum^N_{k=1}|\mathbf{x}(k)|=C\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$$
for all $\mathbf{x}\in\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$.

Conversely, $A\in L(\ell_1,\ell_1)$ then $$\|A\mathbf{e}_k\|=2n|\alpha_n|\leq \|A\|\|\mathbf{e}_n\|_1=\|A\|$$
for all $n$. Hence $\sup_n|\alpha_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you concluded your first non-strict inequality, $||Ax||_1 \leq \lim_{N}\sum_{k=1}^N|x(k)|||Ae_k||_1$? More precisely, can you do that with everything I have said so far, or do you need some extra intermediary results?

Comment: @EpsilonAway: you can use Fatou’s Lemma (sums here can be thought as integrals over counting measure on the natural numbers)

Comment: @EpsilonAway: since you are given the values of $A$ only on the *basic* elements $\mathbf{e}_n$, the extensión to $\ell_1$ can be defined as $\mathbf{x}\mapsto \lim_N\sum^N_{j=1}\mathbf{x}(j)A\mathbf{e}_j$. This coincides with $A\mathbf{e}_n$ when $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{e}_n$ and is well defined if the numeric sequence $n|\alpha_n| $ is bounded. The rest is as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

$\rhd$ The problem is that $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is **not** a bisis of $\ell^1( \mathbb{N})$, therefore your $A$ is not well defined. For example, $u= \left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not in Span($(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$). It is then possible to build such an operator $A$ that is not bounded for any choice of $(\alpha_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

For example, with $f_k = \left(\dfrac{1}{k^n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, one can show that as $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cup (f_k)_{k \geq 2}$ is an independant family of $\ell^1( \mathbb{N})$, and then any operator $A$ such that :

- $A(e_n)= \alpha_n \sum\limits_{i=n}^{2n}e_i$ for all $n \geq 2$ ;
- $A(f_k)= k.f_k$ for all $k \geq 2$

won't be a bounded operator.

$\rhd$ Therefore, to proceed, you **have to** assume that $A(\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} u_ie_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} u_iA(e_i)$. With this, you should be able to proceed and show that :
$$A \text{ is bounded }\;\; \Longleftrightarrow \;\; \exists C\geq 0 : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |\alpha_n|\leq \dfrac{C}{n+1}.$$

Comment: The sequence $\{e_n\}$ is not a Hamel basis for $\ell^1$ but it is a basis of the dense subspace of $\ell^1$ consisting of finite linear combinations of $\{e_n\}$. The operator $A$ is well defined on this subspace. It suffices to show the boundedness on this subspace. Then the operator $A$ extends by continuity to the entire space $\ell^1.$

Comment: This is only true if A is a bounded operator, which is precisely what is asked here.

Comment: If $A$ is unbounded on a dense subspace, it is not bounded. If it is bounded on a dense subspace it extends uniquely to the bounded operator on the entire space. This technique is used for example to show that the Fourier transform is bounded from $L^2 $ to $L^2$ by showing that it is bounded on $L^1\cap L^2$ which is a dense subspace of $L^2.$